# How to display numeric value selected from MS Access in the MessageBox()?

Tags: c#, oledb

Why does my code show the message

> Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

My code:

```
connection.Open();
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
command.Connection = connection;

string cq = "select sum(Fine) from studentbook where S_ID=" + textSID.Text + "";
command.CommandText = cq;
int a = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteReader());
connection.Close();
MessageBox.Show(a.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Change code like this:

```
where S_ID = '" + textSID.Text + "'
```

Also use `command.ExecuteScalar()` instead of `command.ExecuteReader()`:

```
int a = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
```

You should always use [`parameterized queries`](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) by the way. This kind of string concatenations are open for [`SQL Injection`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).